# Call Build vNext task directly

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Build vNext tasks are an awesome improvement over the previous build process. One downside though is that I can't make some tasks conditional. I can create an additional build for every combination, but this clearly scales badly and causes lots of additional work if we have to change some other part of the build.

Instead I'd prefer being able to write my own PowerShell tasks that can call existing build tasks. There is at least one downside to this (if no build asks specifically for the vso-task the build agent won't download it), but considering we are using on-premise TFS and build agents I can live with this.

I tried to do something like the following:

```
$path = get-item "$env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY\Tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.56\NuGetPackager.ps1"
& "$path" -searchPattern $searchPattern -outputDir "$packageFolder" -configurationToPackage $configurationToPackage -nugetAdditionalArgs "$nugetAdditionalArgs -version $nugetVersion"
```

Sadly this causes the following error:

```
2016-04-12T09:50:22.3652811Z ##[error]import-module : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Agent.Interfaces,  
2016-04-12T09:50:22.3652811Z ##[error]Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find 
2016-04-12T09:50:22.3652811Z ##[error]the file specified.
2016-04-12T09:50:22.3652811Z ##[error]At C:\Agent1\Tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.56\NuGetPackager.ps1:19 char:1
```

Now one solution I found on the web indicates that I could add the looked for dlls to the GAC, but I really, really don't want to. Also clearly the tasks work just fine when called from TFS directly, so what configuration am I missing?

I tried adding the folder containing the dlls to the path and even call SetDllDirectory explicitly in the PowerShell, but neither of those help.

Environment: Windows Server 2012 R2 on both build agent and TFS server. TFS 2015 Update 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Powershell task Host that's used by the build agent for 2015 RTM up to Update 2 is a custom host which does creative things to resolve assemblies and handle input/output. These tasks can't be called from outside the agent.

Plus, quite a few build tasks are implemented using Node, so you'll have to detect which one is which and invoke them accordingly.

The build tasks are being [migrated to a new vsts-task-lib](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib), which will support out-of-agent invocation. These would allow exactly what you want.

In the mean time you could take the existing tasks (they're a simple manifest plus script in most cases) and add one `string` parameter to the task in which you stick a variable which you can then treat as the condition. You'd need to replace all the standard tasks. Then push them again. if you keep the ExtensionID and the Task GUID the same, they'll act as in-place replacements. This is probably the easiest way to do what you want without having to perform all kinds of hacks that take away the Task's UI. Just set the version number to something ridiculously higher, like `100.0.1.83`. that way you'll always end up using your version.

**Note:** the new builds are meant to be repeatable, in that calling the same build multiple times they always yield the same results. conditional actions can be captured in custom powershell scripts that are stored in source control. These can be executed as part of the workflow.

Comment: The builds definitely have to be repeatable, no argument there. The conditional actions are all the consequences of some build variable being set to specific values. Adapting the tasks would certainly be the easiest solution, I'm just worried about unwanted side-effects when upgrading. I guess as long as I just increase the minor build version this is unlikely to cause problems (that I have to patch the updated tasks after installing a SP is clear, but acceptable).

Comment: When you upgrade to TFS 2015 update 2 you can publish the tasks using an extension. It would include all the standard build tasks. which would simply allow you to uninstall your extension, create a new version of your extension with all the tasks and then publish a new version of your own extension to the server. As long as the GUID of the build tasks are the same, the highest version will always win. So I'd pick a much higher version. That way you are always sure your task is called.

Comment: Can you link me to more information about extensions for build tasks? Sounds like I'd be able to publish a bundle of tasks in one step and also easily remove it again? That'd be perfect. So far I've seen extensions only as an option to add additional information to the webpage such as the calendar extension.

Comment: I have a few by ld extensions on GitHub that could help as a starting point. Https://www.github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-tfvc-tasks for example. You could indeed do as you suggest, bundle a whole bunch up and Publish them.

Comment: And I have another extension which makes it easy to package and publish your extension. It's not yet possible to use it to publish directly to a TFS server though. https://github.com/jessehouwing/vsts-extension-tasks/wiki